# display different color based on browser

Tags: html, css

I have an exercise question which is:

**Write a snippet of CSS that will display a paragraph in blue in older browsers, red in newer browsers, green in IE6 and black in IE7**

I'm beginning to think this is a trick question as after much googling, the only conditional browser code I can find goes in html like this:

```
 <!--[if IE]>
    According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
    <![endif]-->
```

Although this didn't actually work for me as vis studio just processes this statement as a comment. As far as I can tell it's not possible to write a css snippet to do this, am I right?

Comment: It's an exercise question. Do you think your instructor is trying to trick you by asking you to do something that's not possible? Hint: He/She is not. Hint #2: You're on the right track with your conditional comment, remember that you can include anything within your conditional comment, including HTML tags.....like stylesheets.

Comment: Seems like you should tell your tutor that this question is out of date

Comment: `jQuery.browser` and `jQuery.browser.version` can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really should not be giving you the answer to a quiz... but

```
<!--[if IE]>
<div class="ie">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 6]>
<div class="ie6">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
<div class="ie7">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 8]>
<div class="ie8">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>
<div class="ie9">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
<div class="ie8plus">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<div class="ie9lower">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]> -->
<div class="not-ie">
<!-- <![endif]-->

</div>
```

I'll leave the CSS rules to you ;)

Comment: The above will also allow you to keep all your styles in one stylesheet

Comment: doesn't work for me, vis studio just processes the code as commented and inspecting the element once built does the same, so my 'hello world' text doesn't have any properties to use css rules on, whether I use IE or chrome

Comment: Are you actually seeing the code "as is" displaying on your screen? Ie. it is actually displaying the comments?

Comment: they say a picture is worth a thousand words so here we go: https://postimg.org/image/hov4ceeyb/  As you can see the 'hello world' part doesn't have any property attached. (I did make sure it's within the div). So the last part of the html is like this: <!--[if !IE]>
<div class="not-ie">
<![endif]-->
hello world
</div>

Comment: Well I've seen this answer as correct in other threads so I'll mark it correct even though it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use different css files for any version IE

```
<!--[if !IE]--><link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /><!--[endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]><link href="ie6.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><link href="ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><link href="ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /><![endif]-->
```